# Picture always appears on Facebook as "on line"

Tags: motorola-droid, 3g

My picture is constantly being displayed as "on line" in Facebook even when I am not.  I have completely uninstalled the Facebook app from my Droid 3 and all related apps yet my picture continues to show me as available on Facebook through mobile.  How can I get my picture off.  I am already "off line" on the actual Facebook program - I can't see anyone, but everyone can still see me.  Please help...

Comment: What do you mean by your "picture"?

Comment: What I mean by "my picture" is my Facebook picture is always there on the left side showing that I am on line to my friends which I am usually not even on line.  Even after I click the "stay off line" button so that I should not show on Facebook as being on line - the picture remains showing me available by mobile.  I do not have my phone associated with my Facebook account.

Comment: Blame Facebook, not Android! :C

Answer (score 1):

Log out from Facebook app and Facebook messenger app before uninstalling them. I also had similar problem with early version of Facebook messenger.

Also in my case when my friends tried to send me message the chat box had info saying "Message will be sent to Mobile device" or something like this.

Comment: What I mean by "my picture" is my Facebook picture is always there on the left side showing that I am on line to my friends which I am usually not even on line.  Even after I click the "stay off line" button so that I should not show on Facebook as being on line - the picture remains showing me available by mobile.  I do not have my phone associated with my Facebook account.

Comment: As to the other answer - you must mean that I now have to re-install the Facebook app on my phone so that I may log out before uninstalling it ??  The app has already been uninstalled along with everything I could possibly find on my phone that even remotely could have a connection to Facebook.  I am not sure if you mean for me to re-install it so that I can "log out" and then uninstall the app ??

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant by picture. If I were you I'd try re-installing and logging out. That's what worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work !!  I reinstalled it - logged out of Facebook on the computer - then logged out of Facebook on the phone - then uninstalled it from the phone.   My picture is still there!!  Now What ??